# Simple cross-platform networking framework/library for c++ and Java

Tags: networking, frameworks

I'm going to write simple c++ application, server-client, client-client. I would like to develop server in Java or C++ and client in C++.Since now i haven't got any experiences with networking.

So what C++ and Java library or framework do you recommend to begin with?

I've heard that Java is better that c++ for network applications, is that true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So what C++ and Java library or framework do you recommend to begin with?

[Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) is likely the easiest framework. It allows cross-platform communication between Java, C++ and Python (and probably a few others by now).

> I've heard that Java is better that c++ for network applications, is that true?

No.

Answer (score 2):

Java better than C++ for network applications? **False**.

If you need to use a framework will depend on what you need to do. For example, to have persistent connections among clients and server, you can use **XMPP** protocol. There are very good implementations for Java and C++ so you won't need to write a lot of networking code.

Otherwise, just using C++ and Java socket's API will do just fine.